# In-flight safety instructions for deaf passengers

Tags: air-travel, safety, accessibility

I have never seen this before, but because most of the in-flight safety instructions appear to be replayed recordings these days (at least in my experience for both domestic and international airlines), I would like to find out how this information is being provided to deaf or hearing impaired passengers. I have never seen a sign language interpreter onboard a flight, so I wonder if this is something that people on this site know about.

Comment: I'd note that hearing passengers usually ignore the safety instructions.

Comment: @JonathanReez So maybe we would all pay more attention if it was done in sign language :D

Comment: @JonathanReez I wouldn't say people "ignore" them so much as once you've heard them once, there's really no reason to pay attention on future flights. And I'd bet most people who are flying have flown before.

Comment: There's been a graphic document in the seat in front of me, possibly on every flight I've ever taken before.

Comment: In addition to the safety instructions in every seatback pocket, don't most in-flight safety videos have on-screen closed captioning (or subtitles)?

Comment: @NickWeinberg In Australia at least, most domestic airlines no longer have built-in screens and therefore no safety videos are shown these days. Instead, the onboard staff do a safety demonstration while audio is played.

Comment: @sgroves Yes but you should at least pay attention when they announce the exits; not every plane is the same and you should identify the closest and second closest exits in the event of an emergency, as well as whether your life vest is under, in front or above your seat for instance. You want it to be immediately instinctual your response in an emergency.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your question is basically no different at all to any situation involving a passenger that does not understand the language that the demo is conducted in, which is why passenger carrying aircraft above a certain capacity are required by most national aviation regulatory bodies to supplement the demo with a flight safety card with illustrations depicting the same info as the demo.

Every seat has a flight safety card in the pocket in front of it, thats enough to satisfy the legal and regulatory requirements for the airline.

[image]

For more up-to-date information, there are almost always screens at the gate which can show notices like [image]

Comment: Having a closer look at the safety instruction cards again, they do seem to do a pretty good job of illustrating most of the standard details. However, what about things like the recent incident with Samsung Galaxy phones being banned on flights and other non-standard messages or instructions?

Comment: @MichaelLai those sort of issues should all be dealt with via notices at check-in and at the gate - the only onboard regulatory requirements are for the emergency notices as above, and they have to be understandable by most people, hence limited text and bright illustrations.  Blind and disabled passengers should already have identified themselves prior to boarding and get additional support from onboard staff, deaf people can do something similar but it isnt required.

Comment: @chx bingo, mind if I add that to the answer, with credit to you? :)

Comment: I am sorry, you are right, I have edited the answer, I should've in the first place instead of commenting.

Comment: @Moo if those sorts of issues are already dealt with at check-in and at the gate, then why would they need to do that again as part of the in-flight safety instructions? By the way, I am sensing that there must be some differences between Australian and US requirements since I have never seen such display screen messages at airports.

Comment: @MichaelLai the evacuation and flight safety demo is a regulatory requirement the airline legally has to fulfill in a way that most passengers are likely to understand - not taking a banned device onboard is a restriction the *passenger* is largely responsible for, and the airline is reminding you, but they have no legal obligation to present the information in the same way as the flight safety information.

Comment: @Moo So for completeness of the answer, does that mean if a deaf person asks the onboard staff for additional support, they would politely decline since they don't have the resources or the obligation to provide this information? Perhaps they have a transcript of the safety instruction somewhere handy?

Comment: @MichaelLai the airline employee would hand the passenger their safety card from the pocket in front of them.  Under ICAO rules, which pretty much every national aviation regulatory body adheres to, the only obligation the airline has with regard to doing the demo is that it has to be done orally - the airline has no legal responsibility to ensure passengers understand the demo, so the situation you are asking about is basically the same for deaf people as it is for people who do not speak the language the demo is done in.

Comment: @MichaelLai for Australian regulations on this, see section 14 of the following document https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2009C00093/6aee956d-7d73-42ea-9353-2bbd336ebad8

Comment: @MichaelLai I've updated the answer to show that the situation is basically no different to someone who simply doesnt understand the language the demo is conducted in.

Comment: That card seems pretty old, or does SAS actually still operate smoking flights (well, you can't smoke in the lavatory or while chatting up other passengers if I understand the pictures correctly)

Comment: @oerkelens while smoking has been banned pretty much across the board for a couple of decades now, people do still try and smoke on board, so you still get notices and signs about it.  I *think* the FAA still require an ashtray in a lavatory as part of its regulatory requirements, but you arent allowed to use that ashtray...

Comment: @moo But this card seems to _allow_ smoking in general. The guy that's chatting up the lady should not smoke, but the one sitting in the chair is smoking, and there is no sign indicatie he shouldn't do that. Also the fact that smoking is prohibited in general during taxi, take-off and landing, but in-flight only in the lavatory seems to indicate this card belonged on a traditional smoking flight :) Just remembering the good ol'days :P

Comment: @oerkelens true - looks like smoking is banned during take off and descent, and in the toilets and aisles during flight.  The 737-600/700 dates from the 1990s, so that card may date from a time when SAS allowed smoking onboard.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the safety information card, many flights with in-flight entertainment systems will play a video to provide the safety briefing. It's common for this video to include subtitles, sometimes in multiple languages, for accessibility.

For example, [Delta Air Lines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yflPk0TzEI):

[image: Screengrab of video from Delta safety presentation: flight attendant with subtitled text in English and Spanish "I'll be giving a brief safety presentation"]

Passengers can simply watch the video and read the text instead of listening to the audio.

---

I'd add that it's generally understood and accepted that not every passenger on a flight will be able to understand the safety briefing. I've been on a number of flights where the briefing is only conducted in a language or languages I do not understand, and the airline is not normally violating any regulation by failing to provide me with a translator.

Note that airlines may require passengers travel with a "[safety assistant](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/specialneeds/disabilities/safety_assistant.aspx)" if they aren't able to receive the safety briefing through some means or another, such as "both severe hearing and severe vision impairments."

Answer (score 0):

Airports and Airlines are under pressure to make their materials and communications accessible to the Deaf, mostly because of the ADA laws. They have improved, but this doesn't mean that they are perfect. Many are working with Deaf organizations such as [NAD](https://www.nad.org/) to improve accessibility and other organizations offer advice or interpreters for the Deaf such as [DeafEurope](http://deafeurope.com/) in cases where companies are not so "Deaf Friendly."

Comment: And? It's good to know there's outreach/improvements in the area, but how does this answer the question? (Also ADA is an American concept.)